# Redirect to main page if intermediate page is called

Tags: php

My main page is 
`login.php`

When user enters to this page, he authenticated and after that redirects to `start.php` page

I post variable 'userid' from login.php to start.php here.

```
FB.api('/me?fields = movies,email,name', function(mydata)
                {
                    $.post( function(data)
                    {
                        var $form = $("<form id = 'form1' method = 'post' action = 'start.php'></form>");
                        $form.append('<input type = "hidden" name = "userid" value = "'+userid+'" />');
                        $('body').append($form);
                        window.form1.submit();
                    });
```

What I want to is, if user opens directly `start.php` then he should redirected to login.php automatically.

What short of code I need to add in start.php for this?

`ondocument.ready()` may help me. But how can I use this?

start.php

```
<?php
    $user_id=$_POST['userid'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
        <link href = "css/button.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
        <link href = "css/rateit.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">
        <style>
            .header{
                background-color:#0B6121;
                border:2px solid #0B6121;
                padding:10px 40px;
                border-radius:5px;
            }

            .middle{
                background-color:Yellow;
            }

            .left{ ..............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use,

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['userid'])){
//redirection code goes here
}
?>
```

Add that at the top of the page.

The isset function is checking if the userid element has been sent from the previous page.
Keep in mind that this doesn't take any security like CSRF in to consideration.